# Is there a standard way to prevent native autocompletion?

Tags: javascript, html, w3c

I'd like to prevent my back-office login form to display the auto-completion usually displayed with Firefox for instance. I quickly read some stuff about the attribute `autocomplete` but it doesn't seem to be standard.

Must I use write some JavaScript to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JavaScript required. You are right, the autocomplete attribute is not part of the standard, but neither is the autocomplete feature itself. :)

EDIT:

[Straight from Mozilla:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/how_to_turn_off_form_autocompletion#How_to_Turn_Off_the_Autocompletion_Feature)

> This form attribute is not part of any
>   web standards but was first introduced
>   in Microsoft's Internet Explorer 5.
>   Netscape introduced it in version 6.2
>   -- in prior versions, this attribute is ignored. The autocomplete attribute
>   was added at the insistance of banks
>   and card issuers -- but never followed
>   through on to reach standards
>   certification.

Comment: autocomplete will be standardised in HTML5.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `autocomplete="off"` is not standard, but will work in any modern browser.

```
<form action="..." method="post" autocomplete="off">
    ...
</form>
```